# How to upload data with Microsoft.Net.Http?

Tags: c#

In the past I made a class that shunk the request on an `endpoint`. Now, I create a `dll` that include this method, this is the code that I'm trying to convert on this library:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);
     byte[] responseArray = client. 'there is no upload data method
     // the bottom code is of the old method 
     byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(requestURI, method, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestJson));
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
}
```

In the not portable library `System.Net` I can call `client.UploadData`, but here I see only : postAsync and putAsync, there is a method that independent from the `put` or `post` request allow me to send the data from the `client` to the `server`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old code you used some method passed in `method` parameter to send data with `UploadData` method, and it was probably `POST` or `PUT`. If you do not specify the method for `UploadData`, `POST` is being used. So you should use `PostAsync`or `PutAsync`, based on you current code and the value of `method` parameter you pass to `UploadData`.

The simplest way would be to use something like this:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUrl, data);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The code for PUT would be the same, but with `PutAsJsonAsync`

Comment: Got it, where I could find some example on this?

Comment: There is an extension methods for `HttpClient`: `PostAsJsonAsync` and `PutAsJsonAsync`. You can find it on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.putasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In an HTTP request PUT and POST are the correct ways to transmit data to a server, it does not make sense to send data independently of these methods. When you are using a client such as that available in System.Net this is merely being abstracted away from you.

Comment: Certainly is a good point of view the yours, but in the old code I sent the data independent from the request.